# Indexing data from another sheet based on drop down list selection

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got 2 sheets. Sheet1 and sheet2 for this lets call them.
Cell E3 to X3 will have the formula(with the exception of N3 and O3). Column B has the names to check from B3 onward. Shee2 has the exact same layout as sheet1 so values/locations are same in sheet1 as sheet2. 
Each row(which has 2 merged rows(so B3/B4 merged together etc)) in Column B in sheet1 is a drop down list of all the names in Column B from sheet2.
The situation (assumes all info for sheet2 already inputted):
Name selected from drop down list in B3,
E3 checks B3 for a name.
E3 then checks for match in column B (from B3) from sheet2. 
E3 then pulls all the data from row 3 in sheet2 and inputs into relevant columns(E3 to X3(with the exception of N3 and O3)).

I had a code for how I was doing it earlier when it was in the same sheet. But I've changed how I want to do it and now it's in a separate sheet. 
Before it was checking if the value of B3 matched the value of any other row in Column B and simply taking the data it had there into it's own. But now it's in a separate sheet it works a bit different I think. I tried adding the sheet name in front of the column values in hope of it working but of course it did not.

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B:$B,$B3)>1,INDEX(E:E,MATCH($B3,$B:$B,0)),"")
```

I also tried changing it to just an IF column B in sheet2 = B3 then index but didn't work but I probably didn't do it right.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem properly and referring to your previous questions, my guess would be that you need something like that:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$B:$B,$B3)>1,INDEX(Sheet2!E:E,MATCH($B3,Sheet2!$B:$B,0)),"")
```

Though now the risk of having a circular reference might be absent, so you could probably get away with:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!E:E,MATCH($B3,Sheet2!$B:$B,0)),"")
```

---

If you want to add a sheet name, the syntax is `Sheetname!Range`. If `Sheetname` contains spaces, then you have to surround the name with single quotes, like `'Sheet name'!Range`.

Comment: Second one worked great thanks Jerry. First didn't. It was pretty much what I tried to do before asking. Not sure why doesn't work but the other one does so great. You're a good help!

Comment: @Simon Weird. Can you perhaps explain how the first one doesn't work?

Comment: It doesn't come up with any errors or anything, it just simply doesn't do anything so I couldn't really tell you why.

Comment: @Simon ah, then it means the count was always 1 (or below) which would return blank, which makes sense now that I think about it if you are using Sheet2 as the reference sheet now.